# SharePoint Designer workflow action "Create Item" not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

- I had done very simple operation in designer workflow using "Create
  Item" action to create the list item in my another list.But I am
  afraid to say that I find no luck it to be working
- Can any one help me in knowing the issue in the workflow

[image: Create Item]

Comment: Put a log message before and after create item is called. Check in the Workflow History for an item in the UI till where the workflow is running... There will be error generated if the workflow is getting suspended

Answer (score 2):

I have understood your scenario and tried same requirement in my environment.

You need to check 2 things to make your code in running mode

1- You should not run the workflow from system account

2- The type of data you are copying from one list to another must match datatype else it will not copy in another list.

Here what i have tried in my environment

[image]. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an item in a document library? The dialog suggests that. In that case, you need to provide a file/document. Just metadata is not sufficient.